# Replacing Street Directional Abbreviations (N, S, E, W) with spelled out value (North...) using ArcMap ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, field-calculator, replace

In converting street centerlines to Next Gen 911 schema compliance, how do I iterate a **!St_PreDir!.replace("E", "East")** to include replacing N with North, S with South, and W with West?

I am trying to automate in the ArcMap ModelBuilder and I have no Python experience.

Comment: Are you using the ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: I am still using ArcMap for daily operations.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, an easy way to implement in modelbuilder is to first select rows where ST_PreDIR = "E" then run a field calculate using your replace expression.
Your update will only apply to the selected features.

Then simply repeat the process of select and calculate with N,S & W.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you!